# Structs and GoRoutines, switches instances?

Tags: go, struct, goroutine

I have this function:

```
func New(config *WatcherConfig) *Watcher {
    instance := &Watcher{
        config: config,
        connections: make(map[string]ConnectionInfo),
        lock: sync.Mutex{},
    }

    go instance.Start()

    return instance
}
```

It creates a new instance of `Watcher`, currently there are two `WatcherConfig`. As you can see I start another function called `Start()` using a Go routine.

```
func (w *Watcher) Start() {
    fmt.Println(w.config.PathToLogFile)
}
```

One `WatcherConfig` has a value of `/var/log/openvpn.log` for `PathToLogFile` and another `WatcherConfig` has a value of `/var/log/postfix.log` for `PathToLogFile`. However when I call the `Start()` function using a GoRoutine, it prints `/var/log/postfix.log` twice. If I remove the go routine, so like this:

```
func New(config *WatcherConfig) *Watcher {
    instance := &Watcher{
        config: config,
        connections: make(map[string]ConnectionInfo),
        lock: sync.Mutex{},
    }

    instance.Start()

    return instance
}
```

It will now print `/var/log/openvpn.log` and `/var/log/postfix.log` correctly.

Code that calls `New()`

```
/// ---------
    /// Parse config file
    /// ---------
    configuration, err := config.ParseConfig(*configFileLocation)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }


var watchers []*watcher.Watcher

for _, watcherConfig := range configuration.Watchers {
    watchers = append(watchers, watcher.New(&watcherConfig))
}
```

Why does the go routine "switch" to another instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to fix:

```golang
for _, watcherConfig := range configuration.Watchers {
    watcherConfig := watcherConfig // copy
    watchers = append(watchers, watcher.New(&watcherConfig))
}
```

Range loops in Go are **re-using** the iteration variable, i.e. they are re-using the allocated memory to reduce allocations, in your case it's the `watcherConfig` variable. So the pointer you are passing to `New` with `New(&watcherConfig)` will point to the same memory (since it is re-used). Hence all watchers end up with the same config at the end.

The version without a goroutine in `New` only *looks* to be working correctly because the print statement outputs the value currently stored in the shared memory, but once the loop ends, the watchers will, nevertheless, have a reference to the same, the last, config.

---

There's this [FAQ entry](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines) that discusses the problem.

Comment: I would never have figured that out:) Thanks.

Comment: @TonyP. just keep in mind that this problem arises *only* if you are taking the address of the iteration variable, or referencing it inside a closure that's executed *after* the iteration is done: https://play.golang.org/p/OVL1Xt7RI2X